# how to delete a specific grid in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dynamic, grid, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I want to delete any grid by double tap from the code given below.  I stuck here and i am new to flutter. please, help me. Here is my code:

```
import 'dart:html';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: "Garden",
      home: new Home(),
      theme: new ThemeData(primaryColor: Colors.deepOrange),
    );
  }
}

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  _Homesatate createState() => new _Homesatate();
}

class _Homesatate extends State<Home> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var trees = [
      "m",
      "n",
      "o",
      "x",
      "m",
      "n",
      "o",
      "x",
      "m",
      "n",
      "o",
      "x",
      "m",
      "n",
      "o",
      "x",
      "apple",
      "neem",
      "mango",
      "banana",
      "guava",
      "berry",
      "litchi",
      "apple",
      "neem",
      "mango",
      "banana",
      "guava",
      "berry",
      "litchi",
      "n",
      "o",
      "x",
      "m",
      "n"
    ];
    var gridview = new GridView.builder(
      itemCount: trees.length,
      gridDelegate:
          new SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(crossAxisCount: 7),
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        return new GestureDetector(
          child: new Card(
            elevation: 5.0,
            child: new Container(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              margin: new EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
              child: new Text(trees[index]),
            ),
          ),
          onTap: () {
            showDialog(
                builder: (context) => new CupertinoAlertDialog(
                      title: new Column(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          new Text("GridView"),
                          new Icon(
                            Icons.favorite,
                            color: Colors.red,
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                      content: new Text(trees[index]),
                      actions: <Widget>[
                        new FlatButton(
                            onPressed: () {
                              Navigator.of(context).pop();
                            },
                            child: new Text("Ok"))
                      ],
                    ),
                barrierDismissible: false,
                context: context);
          },
          onDoubleTap: () {
            Visibility(
              visible: false,
              child: 
            );
          },
        );
      },
    );

    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text("Garden"),
      ),
      body: gridview,
    );
  }
}

void main(List<String> args) {
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

here, i want to delete any grid by double clicking. Here, single click wil show the content of grid. I am mostly stuck in these area:

```
onDoubleTap: () {
            Visibility(
              visible: false,
              child: 
            );
          }
```

so, anyone please help me. specially, i don't understand what to do with the child in the double tap portion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Flutter, the UI is the result of your state. So to change the UI, you'll need to handle state. Right now, all cells are always visible.

I would suggest changing the `trees` from just a `String` to an object with two properties, like 'name' and 'visible'.

```
class Tree {
  String name;
  bool visible;

  Tree(this.name, this.visible);
}
```

Then you could define your list like:

```
var trees = [
  Tree('apple', true),
  Tree('mango', true),
  // etc
];
```

The important thing is to define this **outside** of the `build` method, so it would be part of your state.

You can then wrap a `Visibility` widget around the `Card` and pass in the `visible` property of the specific `Tree` object.

```
class _HomeState extends State<Home> {

  var trees = [
    Tree('apple', true),
    Tree('mango', true),
    // etc
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var gridview = new GridView.builder(
      itemCount: trees.length,
      gridDelegate:
        new SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(crossAxisCount: 7),
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        return new GestureDetector(
          child: new Visibility(
            visible: trees[index].visible,
            child: new Card(
              // etc...
  }

}
```

Then in the `onDoubleTap`, you toggle the visibility via `setState`

```
onDoubleTap: () => setState(() {
  trees[index].visible != trees[index].visible;
}),
```

Comment: onDobletap I add this code. but didn't work. should i add more code in this portion. pls help me. i want to delete a grid where i double tapped. pls let me know a little bit more about ondoubletap () portions code. It will help me a lot.

Comment: thank you @dumazy . This is the correct answer. I missed something for the first time but now I get it.